# Android kill the Qt app because of permission issue

Tags: android, c++, opencv, qt5

tham 5 minutes ago

Trying to build an app with Qt5.12.3 and opencv4.1.2(android prebuild version from the [opencv release page](https://opencv.org/releases/)).

- Mobile : Sony xperia XA1 Ultra
- Qt: 5.12.3
- NDK : r19c
- minimum target: 24
- maximum target: 28
- Android library link to : libcamera2ndk.so and libmediandk.so, I link to the libs of api 28, not 24(android-28\arch-arm\usr\lib)
- permissions:
- arch : armeabi-v7a

Because I need to process the frames of the camera at real time, I use the NdkCameraManager to capture the screen of the camera, but this cause the permission issue

Error messages:

```
W RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:353504): avc: denied { read } for name="perf_ioctl" dev="proc" ino=4026533700 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

Edit : Extra so files I add into the project

```
contains(ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH, armeabi-v7a) {
    ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS = \
        C:/Users/yyyy/programs/Qt/android_camera/../../../3rdLibs/Android/android-ndk-r19c-windows-x86_64/android-ndk-r19c/platforms/android-28/arch-arm/usr/lib/libcamera2ndk.so \
        C:/Users/yyyy/programs/Qt/android_camera/../../../3rdLibs/Android/android-ndk-r19c-windows-x86_64/android-ndk-r19c/platforms/android-28/arch-arm/usr/lib/libmediandk.so \
        C:/Users/yyyy/programs/Qt/android_camera/../../../3rdLibs/opencv/opencv_4.1.2-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java4.so
}
```

Maybe I missed some so files?

Comment: Wrong topics and info, app crash because of another reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to ask the user to grant access to the camera at run-time.
So, using [QtAndroid](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroid.html) from [Qt Android Extras](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-index.html) module,
Run this code before the first access to the camera

```
   auto  result = QtAndroid::checkPermission(QString("android.permission.CAMERA"));
    if(result == QtAndroid::PermissionResult::Denied){
        QtAndroid::PermissionResultMap resultHash = QtAndroid::requestPermissionsSync(QStringList({"android.permission.CAMERA"}));
        if(resultHash["android.permission.CAMERA"] == QtAndroid::PermissionResult::Denied)
            // do whatever need if denied
         else
            // do whatever need if granted
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I enable the camera permission manually but it still crash. Exactly the app crashed before I tried to open the camera, I wonder maybe this is because I missed some .so files

Comment: take a look at https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/camera#acameramanager_accessprioritieschangedcallback
Anyway, I think that the problem lies somewhere else

Comment: You are correct, the issue is ACameraManager_getCameraIdList make the app crash, will open a new post to ask why since they are different question. Thanks